# Yii 1.1 Login redirect depending on user role (Role based access control)

Tags: php, yii, rbac

I've searched around and can't seem to find a solution to the problem. I'm a rookie developer, so apologies if this is straight forward.

I'm wanting to have a simple re-direct depending on the user role. I have a "role" row within my "Users" table, and I want them to be directed to the "Index.php" page if they are a "user", and the "Dashboard" page if they are an "administrator".

I understand that it has something to do with the "SiteController", I'm just not sure of the exact code. For a reference, I currently have the following under the "ActionLogin" function -

```
public function actionLogin()
{
$model=new LoginForm;

// if it is ajax validation request
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
{
echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
Yii::app()->end();
}

// collect user input data
if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
{
$model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
// validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
if($model->validate() && $model->login())
$this->redirect(array("Site/Dashboard"));
}
// display the login form
$this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));

}
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks a lot, I'm slowly learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to implement role base access you have to exted the default implementation of Yii, which comes only with user authentication (user is logged or user is guest).

In order to start with role based access, I recommend you to start by implementing your user class by extending the Yii CWebUser class.
Something like:

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {
    /**
    * cache for the logged in User active record
    * @return User
    */
    private $_user;
    /**
    * is the user a superadmin ?
    * @return boolean
    */
    function getIsSuperAdmin(){
        return ( $this->user && $this->user->accessLevel == User::LEVEL_SUPERADMIN );
    }
    /**
    * is the user an administrator ?
    * @return boolean
    */
    function getIsAdmin(){
        return ( $this->user && $this->user->accessLevel >= User::LEVEL_ADMIN );
    }
    /**
    * get the logged user
    * @return User|null the user active record or null if user is guest
    */
    function getUser(){
        if( $this->isGuest )
            return null;
        if( $this->_user === null ){
            $this->_user = User::model()->findByPk( $this->id );
        }
        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

As you can see `User::LEVEL_SUPERADMIN` and `User::LEVEL_ADMIN` are provided by CWebUser. Then in your site controller accessRules() put something like:

```
// Get the current user
$user = Yii::app()->user;

function accessRules(){
    return array(
        //only accessable by admins
        array('allow',
          'expression'=>'$user->isAdmin',               
        ),
        //deny all other users
        array('deny',
          'users'=>array('*').
        ),
    );
}
```

In order to use your new class with role based access, add it in the config/main.php file as an application component:

```
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        //tell the application to use your WebUser class 
        'class'=>'WebUser'            
    ),
),
```

In your views, you can see how it works by using:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isAdmin){
   echo 'Administrator!';
}
if(Yii::app()->user->isSuperAdmin){
   echo 'SuperAdmin!';
}
```

You have to manage the database table for users, and maybe add fields to store the user role constant. Further readings on Role Base Access are:

- [Yii Authentication](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#role-based-access-control)
- [Simple Auth Sistem](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/276/simple-authorization-system/)
- [Simple RBAC](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac)

To continue reading about the code provided in answer, go [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/276/simple-authorization-system/).

### Update

In order to perform the redirect as you mention, try:

```
// collect user input data
if(isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
    $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
    // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
    if($model->validate() && $model->login())
        // If you just want to run the view
        $this->render('dashboard',array('model'=>$model));
        // If you want to reander the action inside the controller
        // $this->redirect( array("site/dashboard") );
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

**Note** that **dashboard.php** file must be placed inside `/protected/views/site` folder.

Comment: Hi Karlos,
Thanks for finding the time to get back to me. I should've explained a little better.

I currently having a working RBAC authorisation system in place, so can identify user types and restrict/grant access depending on each user.

What I'm trying to do is have something like an IF statement where upon logging in it will say "Yes he's an admin, send him to "Dashboard.php", or "Oh he's a "user", send him to "Index.php"

Now I'm assuming this will go under the ActionLogin function in the SiteController. Do you happen to know how to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Then upon login, instead of the redirect sentence do: `$this->render('dashboard',array('model'=>$model));` and create *dashboard.php* file inside */views/site* folder.

Comment: If you want to render the controller action follow the answer update.

Comment: Hi Karlos,
Spot on, it's working! Thank you very much for putting your time and effort into helping me, I really appreciate it.